# Magento tax calculation suddenly calcaluted twice

Tags: magento

A customer of mine suddenly has a strange problem.

For example: 
Product A = 121,--
Tax = 21,-

So the subtotal should be 121,- incl. tax and the grand total also should be 121,- incl. tax.

But the grand total now is 100 incl. tax, so there is a problem with the calculation.

It looks like the tax is calculated good from products:

A product costs 23,95 incl. 21% tax
the subtotal excl. tax is than 19,79
the subtotal incl. tax is 23,95

And now the problem:
The endtotal excl. tax is 15,63 (so the tax calculated twice)
The grandtotal incl. tax is 19,79 (this is the excl. tax price from the subtotal).

Anyone?

Answer (score 8):

OK, this has to be a bit of a guess rather than a definite answer but a classic gotcha that causes the sales tax to be doubled when displaying products inclusive of tax can be caused when you haven't set the shipping origin.

System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Shipping Settings and then set the origin to the country you are actually shipping from (ie your store normally) rather than the default United States.

Comment: I've found it! it was not the shipping settings, but the calculate tax based on after discount instead of before discount!

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! How many years I have been using Magento, and I *still* forget this flippin' setting every time!

Answer (score 0):

GoTo System->Configuration

under sales -> VAT

under Calculation Settings

Set Tax Calculation Based On to Shipping Origin.